# Does the Beis Hamikdash require Mezuzos?

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, mezuzah

The Shema says וּכְתַבְתָּ֛ם עַל־מְזוּזֹ֥ת בֵּיתֶ֖ךָ וּבִשְׁעָרֶֽיךָ - on the doorpost of your houses and gates.

I've always thought of the Beis Hamikdash as God's house [and gates], does the Beis Hamikdash need Mezuzos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fantastic Question!

[Yoma 11b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.11b.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) asks this exact question, and answers that it does not require a Mezuzah:

> יכול שאני מרבה אף הר הבית והלשכות והעזרות ת"ל בית מה בית שהוא חול אף כל שהוא חול יצאו אלו שהן קודש
>
> I might have thought that I include in the obligation of mezuza even the Temple Mount and its chambers and courtyards. Therefore, the verse states: House; just as a house is a place that is non-sacred, so too any place that is non-sacred is obligated in the mitzva of mezuza, excluding those places that are sacred.

Rambam codifies this view ([Tefillin/Mezuzah/Sefer Torah 6:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.6?lang=bi)):

> הַר הַבַּיִת הַלְּשָׁכוֹת וְהָעֲזָרוֹת וּבָתֵּי כְּנֵסִיּוֹת וּבָתֵּי מִדְרָשׁוֹת שֶׁאֵין בָּהֶן בֵּית דִּירָה פְּטוּרִין לְפִי שֶׁהֵן קֹדֶשׁ. בֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת שֶׁל כְּפָרִים שֶׁהָאוֹרְחִין דָּרִין בּוֹ חַיָּב בִּמְזוּזָה. וְכֵן בֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת שֶׁל כְּרַכִּין אִם הָיָה בּוֹ בֵּית דִּירָה חַיָּב. כָּל הַשְּׁעָרִים שֶׁהָיוּ בַּמִּקְדָּשׁ לֹא הָיָה לָהֶם מְזוּזוֹת חוּץ מִשַּׁעַר נִקָּנוֹר וְשֶׁלְּפָנִים מִמֶּנּוּ. וְשֶׁל לִשְׁכַּת פַּרְהֶדְרִין מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהַלִּשְׁכָּה הַזֹּאת הָיְתָה בֵּית דִּירָה לְכֹהֵן גָּדוֹל בְּשִׁבְעַת יְמֵי הַהַפְרָשָׁה:
>
> The Temple Mount, its chambers and courts, synagogues and houses of study which have no residences are exempt, because they are sacred. A village synagogue in which transients lodge requires a Mezuzah. So too, a city synagogue which has a dwelling house attached to it, requires a Mezuzah. None of the Temple entrances had a Mezuzah except the Gate of Nikanor, and the gate within that gate, and the entrance to the Chamber of Parhedrin, because this chamber was the High Priest's residence during his seven days of seclusion (prior to the Day of Atonement).

Answer (score 4):

[See Mezuzah 1:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Mezuzah.1.8?vhe=Talmud_Bavli,_Vilna_1883_ed.&lang=bi)

> שערי העיר שערי הרחובות שערי העזרות הרי אלו פטורים ושל הלשכות שהיו במקדש היו פטורות מן המזוזה והלשכה של בית הפרוה שהיתה בית דירה לכהן גדול ז׳ ימים בשנהב וסוכות היוצרים הרי אלו חייבות במזוזה ור׳ יוסי פוטר:
>
> Gates of a city and gates of streets require a mezuzah. Gates of courtyards are exempt. The chambers in the Temple were exempt from mezuzah. The chamber that was called Beit HaParvah, which was the High Priest’s residence seven days a year, and Sukkot of potters require mezuzot. Rabbi Yossi exempts them.

The Jerusalem Talmud ([Yoma 1.1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51338&st=&pgnum=8)[[4b](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Yoma.4b.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)]) also use the word 'your gates' to exclude the Temple gates.

> א"ר יהודה אף היא גזירה גזרו עליה (שמות יא) בשעריך אית תניי תני פרט לשערי הר הבית והעזרות